# Most recent entry in a group SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have Table in which We can have Same ticket no.for multiple entries.i want to retrieve most recent ticket(of same ticket no.) number based on Initiated on column.

```
Ticket  VendorTicket  InitiatedOn              Comments
198165  test          2012-08-10 16:31:33.707  test
199485  sagar         2012-08-11 12:36:25.720  sagar
199485  sagar1        2012-08-11 14:36:25.720  sagar1
199478  kishor        2012-08-11 12:37:21.923  kishor
```

I have Written this query in T-SQL in Stored Procedure It gives me Error Saying `xObj = {"Incorrect syntax near '.'."}`

My T-SQL

```
`@SQL='Select ''<a href="javascript:editTicketByIDAction('' + CONVERT(VarChar(Max), Ticket) + '')">'' + CONVERT(VarChar(Max),Ticket) + ''</a>'' t1.Ticket,t1.VendorTicket[Vendor Ticket],t1.Comments 
From VendorTickets t1 
WHERE NotifyOn <= GetDate() And NotifyOn Is Not Null AND 
NOT EXISTS
(SELECT * FROM VendorTickets t2 
WHERE t1.Ticket = t2.Ticket AND t1.InitiatedOn < t2.InitiatedOn)'`
```

Comment: What database are you using for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A general solution (works on any database) to this problem is the following:

```
SELECT * FROM [my_table] t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT * FROM [my_table] t2
  WHERE t1.Ticket = t2.Ticket
  AND t1.InitiatedOn < t2.InitiatedOn
)
```

This reads: Get all value from my_table where there is no ticket with the same `Ticket` ID and a more recent date.

Notes:

- This may return duplicates in case there are two "most recent" tickets with identical `InitiatedOn` value.
- Be sure to have appropriate indexes on both `Ticket` and `InitiatedOn` columns

Comment: This is perfect! I've been looking for a way to do this for a while now. +1!

Comment: How come when I do a `JOIN` for one of the fields from t1 no results are returned? For example, if t1 had a `phonenumber` field and I have a `phonebook` table with a `number` field, how do I match the number to the name?

Comment: @enchance: You may get a better answer asking this as a regular Stack Overflow question.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

This will give most recent records from each group

```
select * from  <table> t join
(select Ticket,max(InitiatedOn) as InitiatedOn
from <table>
group by Ticket)a
on t.Ticket=a.Ticket
and t.InitiatedOn=a.InitiatedOn
```

Comment: There is a slight risk of returning duplicates, here. That might be OK with the OP, of course

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT   Ticket,
         VendorTicket,
         InitiatedOn,
         Comments
FROM     (
         SELECT   Ticket,
                  VendorTicket,
                  InitiatedOn,
                  Comments, 
                  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Ticket ORDER BY InitiatedOn DESC) AS Row
         FROM     Table
         ) AS Q
WHERE    Q.Row = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If `row_number() over()` is available for you.

```
select T.Ticket,
       T.VendorTicket,
       T.InitiatedOn,
       T.Comments
from (
     select Ticket,
            VendorTicket,
            InitiatedOn,
            Comments,
            row_number() over(partition by Ticket order by InitiatedOn desc) as rn
     from YourTable
     ) T
where T.rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select t1.* 
from tickets t1 
left join tickets t2 on (t1.ticket = t2.ticket and t2.initiatedon > t1.initiatedon)
where t2.ticket is null;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select * from table where ticket=199485 order by InitiatedOn desc limit 1;
```