# Get latest values in GROUP BY using Laravel Eloquent ORM

Tags: php, orm, laravel

I'm trying to understand how Laravel's Eloquent ORM works and was looking at the following MySQL query:

```
SELECT id, name, date FROM tablename GROUP BY name ORDER BY date
```

The use of `GROUP BY` always returns the oldest values of `name`. Is there a way to return the **latest** value instead?

Comment: This is more an SQL problem than it is a Laravel problem.  GROUP BY is performed before the ORDER BY; and it's not really intended for this.  You might find a solution here http://stackoverflow.com/a/11930734/1269513

Comment: I see, so ORM has yet to handle such complex queries.

Comment: Yesterday I solved it inversing the addition of data in DB. Very sad but works.

Comment: How'd you do it? Pls post the query.

Answer (score 7):

Try following code,

```
Tablename::select('id', 'name', DB::raw('max(date) as latest_date'))
 ->groupBy('name')
 ->orderBy('latest_date')
 ->get()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working SQL query that only gets the latest results that are unique for what you choose with `a.id = b.id` - if you wanted to do unique names, then it'd be `a.name = b.name`.

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.*
FROM tablename a
LEFT JOIN tablename b ON a.id = b.id
AND a.date < b.date
WHERE b.date IS NULL
```