# convert to eloquent

Tags: mysql, sql, eloquent

How can i convert this:

```
SELECT max(id), value FROM <table> GROUP BY value;
```

to eloquent?

Thanx in advance!!

Comment: @xQbert You're right.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16477133/get-latest-values-in-group-by-using-laravel-eloquent-orm?

Answer (score 0):

this should work, you can read more about eloquent in https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#introduction

`Table::select(DB::raw('max(id) as maxId'), 'value')->groupBy('value')->get();`